# Deleting duplicate rows without actual match of column values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following columns id, name, source. Data came from multiple sources and there are duplicate records. I want to delete the duplicate records based on the name value.  The name values are not identical.

Example:

```
1  123David Smith Mr.   Phonebook    
2  David                addressbook    
3  John                 addressbook   
4  John abcde           Phonebook    
5  Sarah                addressbook    
6  9876Bob              Phonebook
```

I want a table that looks like

```
2 David   addressbook   123David Smith Mr.  Phonebook
4 John    addressbook   John abcde          Phonebook
5 Sarah   addressbook
6 9876Bob                                   Phonebook
```

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data (in a table form) and what you do and do not want to delete.  Also, tag the question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you want to delete them.  It looks like you want to combine them.  If I understand correctly, you want a query something like this:

```
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id,
       t1.name, t1.source, t2.name, t2.source
from table t1 full outer join
     table t2
     on t1.source = 'addressbook' and
        t2.source = 'phonebook'
        t2.name like '%'||t1.name||'%';
```